Extra logs from API
Does anyone know how to filter (remove) unnecessary logs from API function calls? They pollute logs) .NET Core. I was trying to confige logging via appsettings.json, but it didn't work. I need to avoid them at all, or better to reduce logs  in the Trace/Info/ modes.
Im using NLog in Program\StartUp, Microsoft Extension Logging in other..
Trace:

UPDATE
appsettings.json:
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": { 
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Error" //<----i hoped it will help
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "Microsoft": "None",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None"
      }
    }
  },

nlog.config:
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file, kafka, console" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore*" minLevel="None" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>

Program:
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ProjectConstants.FOLDER_CONFIGS);
    var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(Path.Combine(path, "nlog.config")).GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Info("init main");
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(path, "appsettings.json"), true);
    Configuration = builder.Build();
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
              webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                  .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                  .UseStaticWebAssets()
                  .UseStartup<Startup>()
                  /*
                  .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                  {
                      logging.ClearProviders();
                      logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                  })
                  */
                  .UseNLog();
          }).UseWindowsService().UseSystemd();
}

logs for API creates automatically.

<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore" minLevel="None"* - does not effecr on anything(.
Update. Thanks to Qiang Fu. Right nlog.config is:
<logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Trace" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
<logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Warn" maxLevel="Fatal" writeTo="file" final="true" />
<logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file, kafka, console" />  


What does your appsettings and/or NLog config for logging looks like? What did your attempt to configure it look like? Please [edit]  that into your question.

Hello. I did it.

Not really. There's no code in the question. How do you configure Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to use NLog? If you use NLog directly instead of .NET's ILogger, the .NET configuration settings will have no effect and the minimum level is Info

Im sorry. Done.

The appsettings affect on defualt logger not Nlog. You need to modify the Nlog.config like following:
    <rules>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Trace" maxLevel="Fatal" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file, kafka, console" />  
    </rules>

The minLevel and maxLevel for "Microsoft.*" should include all levels. (Trace:0 ,Fatal:6)
If you want configuration "write to Console only >= Error (4) level", you could configure like following : (Also you need configure all levels of "Microsoft.*". If not, the left levels will use the "*" settings)
    <rules>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Trace" maxLevel="Warning" final="true" />
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minLevel="Error" maxLevel="Fatal" writeTo="console" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file, kafka, console" />  
    </rules>


See also: NLog v5 - LoggingProvider without any filter and NLog v5 - ASP.NET Tutorial
