Disable default logs for ASP.NET Core application
I'm trying to disable the default logging from an ASP.NET Core application. I'm using NLog with a nlog.config file and I have tried adding the Logging section to the appsettings.json file, but still I'm getting the logs.
This is what I have in the appsettings.json:
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "None",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "None"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "None"
      }
    }
}

These is my initial configuration in Program.cs:
var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog();

In my nlog.config I have this but I don't think the problem is in here:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
    <targets>
<!-- some targets here that I remove to make the code shorter-->
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Console"/>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Logfile"/>
        <logger name="*" levels="Info"  writeTo="dbLogs"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>

Here is the csproj. I just delete a reference to another project (just models) and to a local dll:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <AssemblyVersion>0.0.5.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>0.0.5.0</FileVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Http" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.1.35" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.4"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.3.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Database" Version="5.3.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.3.14" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="9.0.0-rc.2.24474.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="9.0.0-rc.2.24473.5" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


And these are the logs that I'm getting and that I'm trying to disable:

Any idea on how can I disable that logs or what I'm missing?
I had tried adding the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting but that didn't change anything.

I suspect middleware. Are you using something like .UseRequestLogging() .UseLogging() .UseDefaultLogging() etc. elsewhere in Program.cs?

Hi Jonathan, could you share your appsettings.Development.json file ? And maybe we can use same settings in these 2 files and check again.

@omni I'm not. That LogManager.Setup(), ClearProviders() and UseNLog() are the only things that I have for logging

Hi @JasonPan, in the appsettings.Development.json I have the exact same configuration for Logging, I just copy and paste to both files to test

@JonathanGómezPérez May I know which IDE tools you are using? I am using vs2022 and can't find the same picture like yours.

I'm using Rider 2024.2.7

I'm also using builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer() and app.UseRouting(). I don't think that can be the cause for those logs but i don't know.

@JonathanGómezPérez Thanks Jonathan, I downloaded/installed it just know, and I can't see the logs like yours in output windows. Could you share your .csproj file ? If you could let me check your sample project(hide your sensitive information), it may helps us figure out the issue quickly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have seen in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78370228/extra-logs-from-api?rq=2 that maybe can be the rules on the nlog.config file? I 'm going to update the question description to add the csproj

The logs went away when adding the following rule to the nlog.config file:
<rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" final="true" /> <!-- <<<< this rule -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Console"/>
</rules>

The final="True" is to prevent matching any other rule for the loggers on the Microsoft.* namespaces and note that do not have any writeTo attribute.

See also: NLog v5 - LoggingProvider without any filter and NLog v5 - ASP.NET Tutorial

Thanks! I'm going to check that info :)
